# set url to be excuted on paticular time event of a day cron job

Tags: php, linux

I have Linux, PHP installed.

I want to set the cron job which will be executed 11:00 AM.

We can add cron job using crontab command

```
time of execution /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/somefile.php
```

I have experience about adding cron job like above using file path but now I need to add file url in cron job with some query parameter.

something like

```
time of execution /usr/bin/php www.example.com/somefile.php?do=sometask&with=me
```

I have tried above method with url also but it is not executing.

Please suggest 
But

Comment: Couldn't you just set `wget http://www.example.com/somefile.php?do=sometask&with=me` in the crontab? I.e., create a HTTP request.

Comment: @jensgram: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @jensgram `1 11 * * * wget http://www.example.com/somefile.php?do=sometask&with=me` Is this correct

Comment: If you will decide using `wget`, you should use the following params: `wget -q -O- http://www.example.com/somefile.php?do=sometask&with=me &>/dev/null`

Comment: @new user Sorry, didn't get back on SO after I posted. Seems that @Let_Me_Be has already solved it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many options. You could use `curl`.

`/usr/bin/curl www.example.com/somefile.php?do=sometask&with=me &>/dev/null`

Comment: What happen If curl is not enabled? Is there any other method which does not need some other thing to enable/disable?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by enable/disable. You will hardly find a system that doesn't come with `curl` (or `wget`) installed. And if it does, these programs are always in main system repository, so installing them shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: +1 good answer by the way both methods are working could you also add the wget method in you answer so that user can choose one of them